# Format short int to time in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a time column showing up as an `int`. `800` would be `08:00am` and `1300` would be `1:00pm`.

How can I format the `int` so that it appears as 12h time, e.g. `1:13 pm`?

I'm using SQL Server.

Thanks

Comment: How exactly do you want the output? Generally I would transpose the column into a time - it is not like sql server does not ahve a time data type. Or do the text manipulation client side.

Comment: Which version you are using?

Comment: 9.00.4035.00 SP3 Standard Edition

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like below to achieve the required result. Idea taken from [How to convert an integer (time) to HH:MM:SS::00 in SQL Server 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12568408/how-to-convert-an-integer-time-to-hhmmss00-in-sql-server-2008)

```
set @time = 1300

select (@time / 1000000) % 100 + ':' +
       (@time / 10000) % 100  + ':' +
       (@time / 100) % 100  + ':' +
       (@time % 100) * 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the integer to [hh:mm:ss representation of datetime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) and handle formatting (i.e. AM/PM) in the presentation layer:

```
DECLARE @Time INTEGER = 800;
SELECT
-- convert datetime to hh:mm:ss
CONVERT(VARCHAR,
        -- cast hh:mm to datetime
        CAST(-- insert semicolon to get hh:mm format
             STUFF(-- convert integer to string and pad with zeroes
                   RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 4) + CAST(@Time AS VARCHAR), 4),
                   3, 0, ':')
        AS DATETIME),
        108);

SELECT @Time = 1300;
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(STUFF(RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 4) + CAST(@Time AS VARCHAR), 4), 3, 0, ':') AS DATETIME), 108);
```

---

Example selecting from temporary table:

```
CREATE TABLE #Time ( TimeValue INTEGER );
INSERT INTO #Time VALUES (800);
INSERT INTO #Time VALUES (1300);

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,
               CAST(STUFF(RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 4) + CAST(TimeValue AS VARCHAR), 4),
                          3, 0, ':')
                    AS DATETIME), 108) AS Time
FROM #Time;
DROP TABLE #Time;
```

Comment: I don't know where my column values play in to this equation. Could you explain a little deeper please?

Comment: @marc_s I always confuse 2005 and 2008 when it comes to `TIME`...updated.

Comment: @Frantumn Your column name would replace the `@Time` variable in the above code. Updated with example of selecting from temp table.