# Average talk time column SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm need a help from the experts as I'm pulling my hair out. I have a report that shows me counts of records with their descriptions. I'm trying to add in the average talk time alongside the totals and this is not working (it is giving each row) can anyone help? also how would the seconds be converted into HH:MM:SS

```
SELECT 
   CONVERT(varchar(12), dbo.cmp_SimplifyDigital.CallDate, 110) AS CallDate, 
   dbo.CRC.Description, COUNT(dbo.CRC.Description) AS Volume, 
   AVG(DISTINCT dbo.History.TalkTime) AS AVGTalk
FROM 
   dbo.cmp_SimplifyDigital
INNER JOIN 
   dbo.Dial ON dbo.cmp_SimplifyDigital.DialID = dbo.Dial.DialID
INNER JOIN 
   dbo.CRC ON dbo.Dial.CRC = dbo.CRC.CRC
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
   dbo.History ON dbo.Dial.HistoryID = dbo.History.HistoryID
WHERE 
   (dbo.cmp_SimplifyDigital.CallDate = CONVERT(varchar(12), GETDATE(), 110))
GROUP BY 
   dbo.cmp_SimplifyDigital.CallDate, dbo.CRC.Description, 
   dbo.History.TalkTime
```

Comment: sorry guys struggling to add the code in correctly

Comment: I added the code in the question.

Comment: Please update your original post with this.

Comment: cheers guys, still learning this site and SQL. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't take the average of the TalkTime as it is included in your group by clause.  Take it out and you'll get the average TalkTime by dbo.cmp_SimplifyDigital.CallDate, dbo.CRC.Description

Comment: how would I convert this to HH:MM:SS? sorry to be a pain?

Comment: Here are a few ways to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12568408/how-to-convert-an-integer-time-to-hhmmss00-in-sql-server-2008