# How to convert number of hours to time

Tags: sql, sql-server, time

If i have `workhours` as an int represent the number of hours .

How to convert this number of hours to Time in sql server.

---

For example :

IF `workhours = 8` then the time equivalent value = `08:00:00`

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12568408/how-to-convert-an-integer-time-to-hhmmss00-in-sql-server-2008 and there you can find an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your number of hours is always between 0 and 23, you can do this:

```
DECLARE @workhours int = 8
SELECT CAST(
            RIGHT('0'+ CAST(@workhours as varchar(2)), 2) -- pad with a leading '0'
            + ':00:00' -- add minutes and seconds
       As Time)
```