# How to convert INT to hh:mm:ss format in TSQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a select query that has a "start time" column as integer. I want to convert this column to hh:mm:ss format.

"start time" has values like 830, 930, 1500, 1730 that should become 08:30:00, 09:30:00, 15:00:00, 17:30:00

Comment: I would like to use UNIX timestamp instead. And I think sql has `date and time` data types https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396.

Comment: did you come across  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12568408/how-to-convert-an-integer-time-to-hhmmss00-in-sql-server-2008

Answer (score 0):

You need to `CAST` them to `VARCHAR` first and do the manipulation:

```
WITH tbl(tm) AS(
    SELECT 830 UNION ALL
    SELECT 930 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1500 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1730
)
SELECT
    LEFT(RIGHT('0000' + CAST(tm AS VARCHAR(4)), 4), 2)  + ':' +
    RIGHT(CAST(tm AS VARCHAR(4)), 2)
FROM tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you should use this:

```
select CONVERT(varchar(2),[start time]/100) + ':' + CONVERT(varchar(2),[start time]%100) + ':00' 
from table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT
    format ([start time] / 100, 'd2') + ':' + format ([start time] % 100, 'd2') + ':00'
FROM
    MyTable
```