# SQL Server : conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character with string past 12pm

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, type-conversion

For the past few days my code has worked, but today it has the following error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Here is my code:

```
DECLARE @run_time INT
DECLARE @run_duration INT 

SET @run_time = '120609'
SET @run_duration = '2600'

SELECT
    h.step_id,
    CAST(j.[name] AS VARCHAR) as JobName,
    h.step_name,
    CAST(REPLACE(LEFT(CAST(case 
                              when len(@run_time) = 1 then '00:00:0' + cast(@run_time as varchar)
                              when len(@run_time) = 2 then '00:00:' + cast(@run_time as varchar)
                              when len(@run_time) = 3 then '00:0' + cast(left(@run_time,1) as varchar) + ':' + cast(right(@run_time,2) as varchar)
                              when len(@run_time) = 4 then '00:' + cast(left(@run_time,2) as varchar) + ':' + cast(right(@run_time,2) as varchar)
                              when len(@run_time) = 5 then '0' + cast(left(@run_time,1) as varchar) + ':' + SUBSTRING(CAST(@run_time AS VARCHAR),    2, 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(CAST(@run_time AS VARCHAR), 4,2)
                              when len(@run_time) = 6 then cast(left(@run_time,2) as varchar) + ':' + SUBSTRING(CAST(@run_time AS VARCHAR), 2,2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(CAST(@run_time AS VARCHAR), 4,2)
                           END AS TIME), 8), ':', '') AS INT) StartTime
```

I discovered the only time the error appears is when the run_time goes past 120000 (12pm), hence why I've never noticed it before because the agent jobs have ran at 3am. It shouldn't be an issue in the future, but just in case it is I would like a fix for this. I can't find an example anywhere that's similar to my code. Unfortunately casting the results like this is the only way I can get a graph in SSRS to work. (INT > VARCHAR > TIME > INT).

edit - here is a better example of my code using one of the proposed answers:

```
SELECT
    h.step_id,
    CAST(j.[name] AS VARCHAR) as JobName,
    h.step_name,
    CAST(stuff(stuff(right('0000000' + h.run_time, 6), 5, 0, ':'), 3, 0, ':') as time)
FROM
    msdb.dbo.sysjobs j 
    INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory h ON j.job_id = h.job_id
```

Thanks,

Comment: Can you explain what the code is supposed to be doing?  What are examples of the inputs and the results?

Comment: The code is looking at msdb.dbo.sysjobs and msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory, and is getting the start time of the job. Which is an INT, then I am casting as a varchar, then time, the back to an int after removing the colons. So I can plot this on a graph with the start time and job duration, to ensure the etl schedule is running in sequence. Unfortunately due to permissions on the SSRS report I can't use msdb.dbo.agent_jobtime.

Comment: Right off the bat, you are declaring your `@run_time` and `@run_duration` as an `INT` and then setting them as an implicit string datatype. Are you looking for this to ultimately be back to a `datetime` datatype.

Comment: Yes, I declared them for the purpose of this example on the question, as from the table I am getting them they are an INT. I will edit my question with a better example of my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to calculate the start time from a string in HHMMSS format, then this method seems much simpler to me:

```
select cast(stuff(stuff(right('0000000' + str, 6), 5, 0, ':'), 3, 0, ':') as time)
from (values ('120609'), ('0'), ('1001')) v(str)
```

Comment: Thank you, if I can get this to work it certainly shortens my code a lot. I have added an example into my original question of the code in action and I am still getting the same error.

Comment: @Jas . . . Then you would seem to have a string that is not valid as a time format or one that exceeds `'250000'`.  Use `try_cast()` if you want to avoid the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your case the problem is the string which you are trying to convert: "12:20:60"
The converstion to TIME type fails.

```
DECLARE @run_time INT
DECLARE @run_duration INT 
SET @run_time = '120609'
SET @run_duration = '2600'


SELECT
    -- h.step_id,
    --CAST(j.[name] AS VARCHAR) as JobName,
    -- h.step_name,
    --CAST(REPLACE(LEFT(CAST(
    case 
        when len(@run_time) = 1 then '00:00:0' + cast(@run_time as varchar)
        when len(@run_time) = 2 then '00:00:' + cast(@run_time as varchar)
        when len(@run_time) = 3 then '00:0' + cast(left(@run_time,1) as varchar) + ':' + cast(right(@run_time,2) as varchar)
        when len(@run_time) = 4 then '00:' + cast(left(@run_time,2) as varchar) + ':' + cast(right(@run_time,2) as varchar)
        when len(@run_time) = 5 then '0' + cast(left(@run_time,1) as varchar) + ':' + SUBSTRING(CAST(@run_time AS VARCHAR), 2,2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(CAST(@run_time AS VARCHAR), 4,2)
        when len(@run_time) = 6 then cast(left(@run_time,2) as varchar) + ':' + SUBSTRING(CAST(@run_time AS VARCHAR), 2,2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(CAST(@run_time AS VARCHAR), 4,2)
    END ,
    SUBSTRING(CAST(@run_time AS VARCHAR), 4,2)
    --AS TIME)
    --,8), ':', '') AS INT) StartTime
```

Did you check this out?
[How to convert an integer (time) to HH:MM:SS::00 in SQL Server 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12568408/how-to-convert-an-integer-time-to-hhmmss00-in-sql-server-2008)

The best solution should be the one proposed by Gordon

Comment: Yes I did have a look at this one, and I tried it. But whenever my run time was 47 seconds, it is showing as 47 milliseconds instead.

Comment: try with this code: select (@run_time / 1000000) % 100 as hour,
       (@run_time / 10000) % 100 as minute,
       (@run_time / 100) % 100 as second,
       (@run_time % 100) * 10 as millisecond

select dateadd(hour, (@run_time / 1000000) % 100,
       dateadd(minute, (@run_time / 10000) % 100,
       dateadd(second, (@run_time / 100) % 100,
       dateadd(millisecond, (@run_time % 100) * 10, cast('00:00:00' as time(2))))))

Comment: Also, with this code how can I reference the run time in the first select statement without having a from statement?

Comment: See my new answer

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
SELECT
    h.step_id,
    CAST(j.[name] AS VARCHAR) as JobName,
    h.step_name,
    -- CAST(stuff(stuff(right('0000000' + h.run_time, 6), 5, 0, ':'), 3, 0, ':') as time)
     (h.run_time / 1000000) % 100 as hour,
       (h.run_time / 10000) % 100 as minute,
       (h.run_time / 100) % 100 as second,
       (h.run_time % 100) * 10 as millisecond,
       dateadd(hour, (h.run_time / 1000000) % 100, dateadd(minute, (h.run_time / 10000) % 100, dateadd(second, (h.run_time / 100) % 100, dateadd(millisecond, (h.run_time % 100) * 10, cast('00:00:00' as time(2)))))) 
FROM
    msdb.dbo.sysjobs j 
    INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory h ON j.job_id = h.job_id
```

Btw, the CAST drives to error for me, as well

In case you don't want to use the select statement:

```
DECLARE @run_time INT
DECLARE @time_result TIME

SET @run_time = '120609'

SET @time_result = dateadd(hour, (@run_time / 1000000) % 100, dateadd(minute, (@run_time / 10000) % 100, dateadd(second, (@run_time / 100) % 100, dateadd(millisecond, (@run_time % 100) * 10, cast('00:00:00' as time(2)))))) 

select @time_result
```