# How to convert time integer format to datetime in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, timestamp

I have a timestamp column in SSMS with the time expressed as an `integer` like this:

```
8:02:48 written as 80248
```

Is there a way I can use code to convert this timestamp integer to a date format (ie. `HH:MM:SS`)? I've been googling around for a while but have been unable to find something that works.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Do u mean to convert it to time format ?

Comment: What result do you want? A DATETIME or TIME type or just a character string?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12568408/how-to-convert-an-integer-time-to-hhmmss00-in-sql-server-2008

Comment: I would like it expressed as a time type; I'm using SSMS

Answer (score 1):

This worked with your data:

```
SELECT TIMEFROMPARTS(80248/10000, (80248 - 80248/10000*10000)/100, (80248 - 80248/10000*10000) - (80248 - 80248/10000*10000)/100*100, 0, 0)
```

Comment: This gave me exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: Mark it as the answer, please!