# change int data type into hours

Tags: t-sql, ssms

I have a column which contains the SLA-times of Tickets. The current data type for the SLA-times is INT, but because I want to do a calculation with the SLA-time I need to convert it somehow to Hours. One of the SLA-time is 48 hours, so do I need do days aswell since I know that SQL works with 24 hours only.

Thanks,

Shabby

Comment: Please post a sample of your data, the desired output and the code you already wrote to solve the problem.

Comment: This answer may help - https://stackoverflow.com/q/12568408/2570277

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert an integer (time) to HH:MM:SS::00 in SQL Server 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12568408/how-to-convert-an-integer-time-to-hhmmss00-in-sql-server-2008)

Comment: What does the int value represent? Hours? Minutes? Seconds? If you have a report date on the ticket and you want to calculate the SLA date, you can probably simply use `DateAdd`

Comment: Thanks everyone for ur reply. The situation has changed a bit. I have a Column which I did not know of which already has the SLA-time saved. The only issue is that I have one SLA-time where the resolve time is 48 hours and since I the SLA-time column is a data type "time(7)" I cannot edit it do 48 hours. It only accept till 23:59:59.9999999. What can I do here? Thanks

Comment: SQL Server Time data type is designed for time-of-day (as you can easily understand from it's range). If you want to store a time span an int is a better choice, as long as the column name is descriptive (i.e `HoursBetweenCreateDateAndSLA` or `SecondsBeforeTimeOut`) so that the next person that need to work with the database can easily understand what's the meaning of the number.

Comment: Is it possible to use the int for a calculation for my goal? So I want to use the SLA-time to calculate if a certain ticket is over its SLA-time. Currently, I have a Column with the Created date which is a datetime2 data type.
So how I see this happening: 
I add the SLA-time to the Created date and then I have the so-called deadline. But I cannot add an int to datetime2. Please guide me in this one since I am not an expert...

Comment: @Shabby to your last comment, maybe just use dateadd()?  So something like dateadd(hour, SLA-time here, CreateDate) >= DeadLineDate... Is that what you're after?  dateadd() is what you would use to add days, hours, minutes, etc to a datetime value.

Comment: If you reword your question, added some sample data and your expected output that would be really helpful in getting assistance.