# Unix time show 1h with empty value

Tags: mysql, sql, time

I want to show the summary of all values as visual date. For example:

| Key | Val1 | Val2 | Val3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 125 | 545 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 467 | 0 |

Here, `val1`, `val2` and `val3` are in seconds. In SQL, they are saved as `BIGINT(20)`.

Those values represents the time for each users doing something different. So, the user with key 1 stay 125 seconds on the page which is named val1, 545 seconds on page val2 and 0 on val3.

The objective is to know which page is the more used, where users stay lot of time. So, I want to make a readable time and convert "3600 seconds" into "1h" for example.

More exactly, I want to show as something like this:

| Val1 | Val2 | Val3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2min 05s | 16min 52s | 0s |

I tried to used something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12568408/10952503) but it's only for `sql-server`.

Actually, I made this:

```sql
SELECT
FROM_UNIXTIME(SUM(val1), '%dd %hh %imin') as val1,
FROM_UNIXTIME(SUM(val2), '%dd %hh %imin') as val2,
FROM_UNIXTIME(SUM(val3), '%dd %hh %imin') as val3,
FROM my_table;
```

But, this is my result:

| Val1 | Val2 | Val3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1d 1h 2min 05s | 1d 1h 16min 52s | 1d 1h 0min 0s |

Even if empty values (such as "0min") don't disturb me, the `1d 1h` is the issue.

How can I made them as 0h or remove them is there are empty ?

Comment: What are you attempting to achieve with this summation

Comment: _Small Point_ the (99) specification of INT types is deprecated, a simple INT or BIGINT is now all that is required

Comment: I want to get the time of all users on the val1, va2 category ... So, key 1 & key 2 represent user, and val1/val2 their time of the page1/page2 for example. And I want to have a visual value for all the time, because I can't read 1500s

Comment: Show an example output please, in your question, use the EDIT link

Comment: Sure, I just add some explaination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the `1d` because the unix epoch is `1st Jan 1970` so even if you have a var containing zero, the day represented by zero seconds is the `1st` if you were outputting the month you would be getting `January` and the year, you guessed it `1900`

> This begs the question, what are you actually trying to achieve with this code, my guess is this is not going to do it.

This may be better for your requirement

```
SELECT CONCAT(
            FLOOR(TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(val1)), '%H') / 24), 'days ',
            MOD(TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(val1)), '%H'), 24), 'h:',
            TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(val1)), '%im:%ss')
        ) AS Val1,
        CONCAT(
            FLOOR(TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(val2)), '%H') / 24), 'days ',
            MOD(TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(val2)), '%H'), 24), 'h:',
            TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(val2)), '%im:%ss')
        ) AS Val2,
        CONCAT(
            FLOOR(TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(val3)), '%H') / 24), 'days ',
            MOD(TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(val3)), '%H'), 24), 'h:',
            TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(val3), '%im:%ss')
        ) AS Val3
```

RESULTS

```
'0days 0h:02m:05s', '0days 0h:16m:52s', '0days 0h:00m:00s'
```